# Just need a answer/solution for 2D number array

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I probably doing some total mess here but I've been sitting with this question for days. So far I figured out the way to find corresponding locations yet it's not quiet right.

So sorry for lack of info or explanation, hope some expert ppl like u can help me.

Basically user inputs an integer, then the have to print out 2D number array that looks like this:

```
input: 3           input: 4              input: 5
output:            output:               output: 
1 2 6               1  2  6  7            1  2  6  7 15
3 5 7               3  5  8 13            3  5  8 14 16
4 8 9               4  9 12 14            4  9 13 17 22
                   10 11 15 16           10 12 18 21 23
                                         11 19 20 24 25
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void SomeFunction(int x);
int main(void)
{
    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    SomeFunction(N);
    return 0;
}
void SomeFunction(int x)
{
   // int array[row][col];
    for(int val=1; val<=x*x; val++)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=x; i++)
        {
            for(int j=1; j<=x; j++)
            {
                for(int k=2; k<=2*x; k++)
                    { if((i+j)==k) printf("%2d ",val); }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please be aware that this site is not a free code writing service. Take the [tour] and read this: [ask].

Comment: Don't mess up your question when it has been edited properly. Don't post pictures of text.

Comment: Hint: The field width can come from another `int` parameter by using `*` for the field width, e.g. `printf("%*d ", width, val);`. Now you just need to determine the number of decimal digits in the value `x*x` in order to calculate the width. Use the same width for every number in the table. (I have not checked the other parts of your code yet, but using 4 nested loops to print a 2-D table looks wrong!)

Comment: A pretty simple approach could be creating a `n*n` array and marching along the digagonals (`++x; --y;` for SW->NE direction, `--x; ++y;` for NE->SW direction). When ever you reach 0 on decrementing move to next row/column and swap direction. Finally you can print the matrix filled that way row by row.

Answer (score 0):

The value to be printed at each position in the matrix is a weird function of the matrix dimension, the row, and the column. The maximum value to be printed is the square of the matrix dimension. To keep the output columns aligned, determine the column width from the number of decimal digits in the maximum value.

The magical calculation in the code below determines which bottom-left to top-right sub-diagonal the current position is on. If the position is in the top-left half it counts the number of elements in the triangle above the current sub-diagonal, otherwise it counts the number of elements in the triangle below the current sub-diagonal. Then it adds on the position within the current sub-diagonal, depending on the direction that numbers increment for that sub-diagonal. If the current position is below the main bottom-left to top-right diagonal the value needs to be subtracted from the maximum value. A few adjustments of plus or minus 1 are required at various steps of the above procedure to end up with the correct value for the current row and column.

The code below implements the above procedure:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void SomeFunction(int x);

int main(void)
{
    int N;

    scanf("%d",&N);
    SomeFunction(N);
    return 0;
}

void SomeFunction(int x)
{
    int width;
    int sep_ch;
    int tl;
    int br;
    int val;
    int max_val;
    int i;
    int j;
    int jj;
    int is_br;

    /* The maximum value to be printed is the square of x. */
    max_val = x * x;
    /* Determine the number of decimal digits in the maximum value. */
    val = max_val;
    width = 1;
    while (val > 9)
    {
        width++;
        val /= 10;
    }
    /* Do each row. */
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        /* Initialize magical top-left and bottom-right numbers for each row. */
        tl = i - 1;
        br = x + x - tl;
        /* Do each column. */
        for (j = 1; j <= x; j++)
        {
            /* Adjust magical top-left and bottom right numbers. */
            tl++;
            br--;
            is_br = (tl > br);
            if (is_br)
            {
                /* Bottom-right part. */
                val = br;
                jj = x - j + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                /* Top-left part. */
                val = tl;
                jj = j;
            }
            /* Alternate the direction for magical diagonal stuff. */
            if (val % 2)
            {
                val = val * (val - 1) / 2 + jj;
            }
            else
            {
                val = (val + 1) * val / 2 + 1 - jj;
            }
            if (is_br)
            {
                /* Adjustment for bottom-right part. */
                val = max_val - val + 1;
            }
            sep_ch = j < x ? ' ' : '\n';
            printf("%*d%c", width, val, sep_ch);
        }
    }
}
```

In the `printf` format specifier `"%*d%c"`, the `*` specifies that field width for the conversion that follows (`d`) is set by an argument of type `int`, so the whole `"%*d%c"` format specifier expects an `int` for the `*` field width, an `int` for the `d` conversion, and an `int` for the `c` conversion.

**Example**

Input:

```
11
```

Output:

```
  1   2   6   7  15  16  28  29  45  46  66
  3   5   8  14  17  27  30  44  47  65  67
  4   9  13  18  26  31  43  48  64  68  85
 10  12  19  25  32  42  49  63  69  84  86
 11  20  24  33  41  50  62  70  83  87 100
 21  23  34  40  51  61  71  82  88  99 101
 22  35  39  52  60  72  81  89  98 102 111
 36  38  53  59  73  80  90  97 103 110 112
 37  54  58  74  79  91  96 104 109 113 118
 55  57  75  78  92  95 105 108 114 117 119
 56  76  77  93  94 106 107 115 116 120 121
```